# Publish to Azure Adding Files Individually during deployment

Tags: .net, azure, model-view-controller, publish

I am publishing MVC apps to my Azure account from two different PCs.  One PC (running VS 2017 15.4.3) publishes fast, with output like

```
2>Adding ACLs for path (10MinutesIter420171115083013)
2>Publish Succeeded.
2>Web App was published successfully
```

The other PC (running VS 2017 15.4.4, also seen in 15.3.3) publishes slowly with output like

```
2>Adding ACLs for path (10MinutesIter320171115082232)
2>Adding file (10MinutesIter320171115082232\ApplicationInsights.config)
2>Adding file (10MinutesIter320171115082232\bin\10minutesIter3.dll)
2>Adding file (10MinutesIter320171115082232\bin\10minutesIter3.pdb)
```

...and so on

The examples on the two PCs were both first publishes to Azure after a File | New of the Project, going to the same Resource Group, both using the Web Deploy publish method.  Project Properties are the same, excepting project names.

What causes this to happen and how can I stop the individual file copy?

Answer (score 0):

> What causes this to happen and how can I stop the individual file copy?

Based on my experience, it seems that there is no relationship with VS version.

If we use VS to publish the Website to Azure, it seems that we can't stop the individual file.

I assume the root reason in your case is that when you publish the website from one of you PC first time it will copy all of the files to Azure webApp, and then publish with same content from another PC although first time if you **uncheck** (default is unchecked) **Remove additional files at destination**. It will check the remote and locally. If there is no difference then it is **no adding file** action.

[image]

If we don't want to publish the individual file, we could use Azure kudu tool(https://{yourwebsite}.scm.azurewebsites.net). You could zip the project and drag to kudu console directly.

[image]